# How can I achieve the opposite of kde-open?

Tags: terminal, emacs, kde, konsole, emacsclient

Is there any way to achieve the opposite of what kde-open does in KDE? I mean, I want to be able to open files using emacs inside the terminal, instead of using the X version of emacs. I already run emacs as a daemon and run the client instances in konsole, but I also want to be able to open files from Dolphin or Thunderbird or any other app using the same konsole run instance of emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Run System Settings, search for MIME Types, find the types in the tree you want to be able to open with emacs. For each type, press the `Add…` button and select the emacs daemon. See the emacs wiki for the specific command-line incantation and the context-sensitive help for the meaning of the various `%` placeholders. Finally press `OK` to change the settings.

From then on, `Open with emacs daemon` will appear in the context menu of files. When you select this, the emacs daemon will be passed the name/location of the file, in turn emacs will open and load the file.